# How can I find the min value of an array in a custom condition in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have to custom types, which I am building an array of it, like this:

```
struct MyType {
    var id: String
    var value: Double
}

struct CustomObjectType {
    var size: CGFloat
    var myType: MyType
}
```

Here is my array:

```
let collection: Array<CustomObjectType> = [CustomObjectType(size: 350.0, myType: MyType(id: "A", value: 0)),
                                       CustomObjectType(size: 200.0, myType: MyType(id: "B", value: 1)),
                                       CustomObjectType(size: 170.0, myType: MyType(id: "C", value: 2)),
                                       CustomObjectType(size: 200.0, myType: MyType(id: "D", value: 3)),
                                       CustomObjectType(size: 200.0, myType: MyType(id: "E", value: 4))]
```

---

Here I am trying to find max and min with my custom condition, but it does not work for finding min value.

```
let maxElement = collection.max(by: { lhs, rhs in
    
    if (lhs.myType.value < rhs.myType.value) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
    
})

let minElement = collection.min(by: { lhs, rhs in
    
    if (lhs.myType.value > rhs.myType.value) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
    
})


print(maxElement?.myType.id, maxElement?.myType.value)
print(minElement?.myType.id, minElement?.myType.value)
```

result:

> Optional("E") Optional(4.0)

> Optional("E") Optional(4.0)

Comment: Your if statements here don’t do anything, btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`max(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/max(by:)) and [`min(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/min(by:)) take a predicate function named `areInIncreasingOrder` which should return true iff the predicate's first argument is **less than** the predicate's second argument.

But when your code calls `min(by:)`, it is passing a predicate that returns true if its first argument is **greater than** its second argument. This makes `min(by:)` return the maximum instead of the minimum.

So, change this:

```
    if (lhs.myType.value > rhs.myType.value) {
```

to this:

```
    if (lhs.myType.value < rhs.myType.value) {
```

Comment: You should mention that the parentheses are unnecessary because the `{}` are always required in Swift. People use `()` in other languages to safeguard against optional `{}`.

Comment: @Jessy:  using `()` does help me and specially Xcode to compile code easier and faster, using `()` would not give a down side! If you do not use `()` and you give more infer jobs to Xcode in some situation with lots of codes, Xcode would be confused and it would through unable to type-check error. I am sure you had such issue before, so using `()` would help to avoid such errors.